# load Image from assets folder to ImageView loses transparency

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, transparency, assets

I hope someone can help me with this issue. 
I'm loading Bitmaps from the assets folder and displaying them afterwards. So far so good, and everything works pretty well **except** that all of my pictures loses transparency.

This is how my XML looks like

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture_iv"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/prod_2"/>
```

and this is how i load the pictures from Assets.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String file) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(file);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, op);

    return bitmap;
}
```

These are the lines inside my Activity.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) a.findViewById(R.id.picture_iv);
iv.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAssets(getActivity(), picPath));
```

I already tried suggestions related to my problem like
to set 
android:cacheColorHint=@android:color/transparent 
or
imageView.setBackgroundColor(0);

but nothing helped.
Can someone point me the right direction? I'm lost.

Thanks in advance,

---

### Edit

I use PNGs and they all have transparency. By moving the pictures inside the drawable folder an load them by **iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture) or android:src="@drawable/picture"** will display it how it should, with transparency;

Just the loading from Assets seams to make problems.

Comment: you are using .png? because .jpg you know doesnt support transparent

Comment: yes, i use .png files.

Comment: did you try it with out loading it with the options?

Comment: i also try to just load the picture. nothing changed. the pictures still have a white background. I also tried to load the pictures with the lazyList, still white background.

Comment: your 100% positive that your images have transparency? maybe try iv.setAlpha(255); 0-255 for alpha transparency

Comment: it should work just how you have your code, im really confused

Comment: if i load the picture via iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture) it shows the picture correctly with transparency. It is possible because there are inside assets folder?

Comment: did you try this it works for my imagebuttons and you can use it on a imageview i just never tried it because i load my imagebuttons like that  android:background="@null"

Comment: Finally i found what i did wrong. I had an copy of my pic without transparency. The one i tested with had transparency the other not. @JRowan: Thank you four your help!.

Answer (score 0):

lnstead of using ImageView try using ImageButton,since its transparent it will look like an ImageView